# multiple INSERT with django form

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I'm trying to create a django form based on the model. The model contains fields: username, date, shift, department, team. Team and Department are defined in different app and are extending the user through UserProfile. I would like to have a table that is generated automatically based on the number of days in the month and users from department and look more less like that:

```
xxxxx | Day1   | Day2   | Day3   | ... | Day31   |
--------------------------------------------------
User1 | Shift1 | Shift2 | Shift3 | ... | Shift31 |
--------------------------------------------------
User2 | Shift1 | Shift2 | Shift3 | ... | Shift31 |
--------------------------------------------------
User3 | Shift1 | Shift2 | Shift3 | ... | Shift31 |
```

where user and day values will be added during the generation of the table and shift will be the dropdown box.

INSERT to the database should be constructed for each day (user1, day1, shift1, department, team) where department and team should be taken automatically based on the username from UserProfile.

I do not know where to start. I've looked at django formset and it would seem a way to go but the formset is generating a HTML table code and all fields are from the form would be in the table. Additionally I would like the possibility to change the generated table within the same view.

I would be very grateful if you can point me to the documents that might help me.

Comment: I'm not sure if what you want is a table with different numbers of columns for each month; usually SQL columns are things that you know in advance, not things you need to check at runtime. Are you sure you wouldn't be better off having a `Shifts` table that contains a foreign key to `TimeSlot`, `Day` and `Month`, then having another `Assignment` that joins together `User` and `Shift`?

Comment: The SQL table layout is ID, User, Day, Shift, Department, Team. What I'm trying to do is to have multiple inserts (one insert for each day for each user). Let's say that if we have 3 users and month has 31 days it will create 93 of User, Day, Shift, Department, Team. To be honest I do not even know how to start and if what i'm trying to do the way that I want to do is a good approach.

Comment: Is `User` a string or a foreign key into another table?

Comment: @PatrickCollins `User` is a foreign key.